# image path for a phtml file

Tags: magento2, image, paths

Hello I would like to add a image to a phtml file. however it didn't get use to the magento code to get the image path

```
<img src="{{media url='/ca_flag.png'}}"/>
```

Somehow the image address was translate to something like this

```
www.domain.com/%7B%7Bmedia%20url='/ca_flag.png'%7D%7D
```

**what should I use?**

**Thanks**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For **template** files:

**Images** in `Vendor/theme/Vendor_Module/web/images` or `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/images/`

```
<img src="<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('Vendor_Module::images/image.png'); ?>" />
```

or if **images** are in `Vendor/theme/web/images/`

```
<img src="<?php echo $block->getViewFileUrl('images/image.png'); ?>" />
```

For **CMS Static Blocks** or **Pages**:

**Images** in `Vendor/theme/Vendor_Module/web/images` or `app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/images/`

```
<img src="{{view url='Vendor_Module::images/image.png'}}"/>
```

or if **images** are in `Vendor/theme/web/images/`

```
<img src="{{view url='images/image.png'}}"/>
```

Comment: thanks! very informative

Answer (score 2):

Put your image inside **app/design/frontend/Vendor/Theme/web/images** and call it like -

```
<img src='<?php echo $this->getViewFileUrl('images/demo.png'); ?>' alt="Demo">
```

Comment: yes, your solution also works too, thanks!